# ColdFusion Component Not Returning Query

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

I have tried, off and on, for about 6 months or so to figure out CFC's but never could get it. So now I have SQL and LDAP queries scattered around in different pages that I would like to consolidate into a component. The query below works in it's own CF page, (I've omitted some of the query details for the post) but I'm getting a blank page instead of any results. This is my queries.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent>    
    <cffunction name="EmployeeQuery" access="public" returntype="query">    
       <cfargument name="EmployeeID" required="yes" type="string"> 

       <cfldap action = "query" 
             name = "EmployeeAdd"
             attributes = "distinguishedName, displayName"
             filter = "sAMAccountName=#Arguments.EmployeeID#" 
             start = ""        
             scope="SUBTREE"
             maxrows="1"
             server = ""
             username=""
             password=""
             separator=";" />    
       <cfreturn EmployeeAdd>    
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

I've got a simple entry form where I enter text, click submit, and on the action page I have:

```
<cfif IsDefined("form.btnEmployeeAdd")>    
    <cfinvoke component="queries" 
         method="EmployeeQuery" 
         cfinvokeargument  
         name="EmployeeID" 
         value="#form.txtEmployeeID#">
    <h3>Confirm Employee Entered</h3>
    <cfoutput>#EmployeeAdd.displayName#</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

My result is a blank page, I don't even get the `h3` text. As mentioned, all this works fine in .cfm pages, but it craps the bed when I try to put it in a .cfc. As with all documentation on this, there's so many different ways to do this, but nothing I've tried works so I was hoping I could get a push in the right direction.

Comment: Baby steps lead to happiness.  Start with something simpler like returning "hello world".  Then return the current date and time.

Comment: Nothing to do with your issue but do not forget to VAR/LOCAL scope *all* function local variables, including query names, ie `EmployeeAdd`. Otherwise, you introduce the potential for hard to trace threading problems if the component is ever stored in a shared scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `cfinvoke` is missing a `returnVariable`

```
<cfinvoke component="queries" method="EmployeeQuery" returnVariable="EmployeeAdd">
  <cfinvokeargument  name="EmployeeID" value="#form.txtEmployeeID#">
</cfinvoke>
<h3>Confirm Employee Entered</h3>
<cfoutput>#EmployeeAdd.displayName#</cfoutput>
```

Alternatively if you're on CF10 or higher you could do this instead of your `cfinvoke`

```
<cfset employeeAdd = new queries().EmployeeQuery(form.txtEmployeeID)>
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, I added the cfinvokeargument name after I posted but it still didn't work. However your <cfset> worked, we're on CF11. However I had another problem. Originally I had the querries.cfc in the root folder along with my application.cfc, so I moved it to the root of this particular application and it worked with your cfset, still doesn't work with my cfinvoke, but no worries. I thought from what I had read, that you could put these cfc's in the root so they would be available to other apps. Do I need to put these query methods in the application.cfc?

Comment: You can reference a folder structure such as `new folder.path.queries()`

Comment: @toleolu - Pankaj is correct.  `cfinvokeargument` is not an attribute. It is a separate tag that must be nested *inside* the cfinvoke. So your original syntax (and the cfinvoke example above) are incorrect.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back on this, as usual, I get pulled off this project to deal with other server related issues, and then it takes me awhile to get back up to speed on things. Thanks again to everyone who replied, I really do appreciate the patience and assistance I get here. Next to ordering pizza, Stack Overflow is the best thing on the net!!!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code to invoke the cfc method, it seems like you are doing it in a wrong way. You have added `cfinvokeargument` inside `cfinvoke` as an attribute. `cfinvokeargument` should be added to `cfinvoke` body, instead. And as @matt suggested you need to add `returnvariable` attribute to `cfinvoke` in order to get results returned from the method. Like this.

```
<cfinvoke component="queries" method="EmployeeQuery" returnVariable="EmployeeAdd">
     <cfinvokeargument  name="EmployeeID" value="#form.txtEmployeeID#">
</cfinvoke>
```

Also as @matt suggested, if you are using `cf10` or higher you can use `new` to instantiate the cfc and then call the method using `.` notation. Like this.

```
<cfset employeeAdd = new queries().EmployeeQuery(form.txtEmployeeID)>
```

Comment: Thanks Pankaj for clearing that up for me. I opted for the new queries method since we are on CF 11.